# Why is it not possible to call locale-gen with sudo inside a docker container?

Tags: docker, locale

```
$ sudo docker run -it --rm --privileged=true debian-jessie su - dib -c /bin/bash
bash: cannot set terminal process group (-1): Inappropriate ioctl for device
bash: no job control in this shell
dib@4a199f1d95f9:~$ sudo locale-gen
Generating locales (this might take a while)...
  en_US.UTF-8... done
$
```

At this point the docker container exists (not running any longer).

On the other hand, when using:

```
$ sudo docker run -it --rm --privileged=true debian-jessie /bin/bash
root@55e8d2ab53f1:/# locale-gen
Generating locales (this might take a while)...
  en_US.UTF-8... done
Generation complete.
root@55e8d2ab53f1:/#
```

`locale-gen` runs fine without problems and the docker container continues to run.

Can somebody please explain, why the `locale-gen` runs fine in the second example but not in the first?

Are there any solutions or workarounds running `locale-gen` with `sudo`?

---

Technical background: the docker images were generated with [diskimage-builder](http://docs.openstack.org/developer/diskimage-builder/) from OpenStack. I tested this with three images: debian-jessie, debian-stretch and ubuntu-trusty - all gave the same results.

Comment: Do you need sudo? Why not start your container as root?

Comment: The tool I'm using does it in this way: yes I need it as described in the question.

Answer (score 0):

For the files:

Did not find the root cause - but a workaround: starting the docker with `runuser` instead of `su` solved the problem for me:

```
sudo docker run -it --rm --privileged=true debian-jessie runuser -l dib -c /bin/bash
```